# What's with the [covariance] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105347/contravariant-and-covariant-vectors-conceptual-problem) just made me look at the tag [covariance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covariance), and I didn't like what I saw. The tag is a mismatched collection of questions about

- Lorentz covariance of theories in relativity,
- covariance of a physical quantity under Lorentz transformations,
- covariant derivatives,
- the differences between covariant and contravariant vectors, and
- statistical covariance.

For a tag to be useful it needs to refer to a coherent set of connected questions; by that metric this tag is useless. I therefore propose we instate the tags

- [relativistic-covariance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relativistic-covariance) for the first two,
- [covariant-derivative](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covariant-derivative) and
- [covectors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covectors).

While [statistical covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) has huge traction in physics (e.g. [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.1869)), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23719/autocorrelation-functions-pair-correlation-functions) is our only statistics covariance question and it's hardly about that, so I propose that tag be dropped. If needed further down, the tag [statistical-covariance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistical-covariance) can be introduced.

I will implement these changes over the weekend (so I don't dump forty questions on the front page in one go) unless there are any objections or better proposals.

To help prevent this happening again, I also propose we blacklist the [covariance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covariance) tag. Setting up [covariant-vectors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covariant-vectors) as a synonym for [covectors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covectors) will ensure it will come up when someone tries to use [covariance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covariance), and having appropriate tag wiki excerpts for the tags should help guide people to the correct tag.

Answer (score 4):

I) Specifically about covariance:

1) The [covariance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covariance) tag is supposed to cover whatever-notion-the-physical-system-in-the-question-is-covariant-under, typically relativistic covariance, but also more abstractly, e.g., contravariant and covariant tensors not necessarily in the context of relativity.

All other uses of the [covariance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covariance) tag than the above are wrong.

2) Covariant derivatives in differential geometry should be tagged [differential-geometry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry) or [gauge-invariance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gauge-invariance) and perhaps [differentiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differentiation). (The [covariance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covariance) tag could apply here if the main topic of the question is point 1.)

3) Gauge Covariant derivatives should be tagged [gauge-invariance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gauge-invariance) and perhaps [gauge-theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gauge-theory) and [differentiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differentiation).

4) Covector, bivector, differential forms, etc, should typically be tagged with [differential-geometry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry) or [tensors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensors).

5) Statistical covariance, average, etc, should be tagged with [statistics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) (which in turn should only be used for [statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics) in the mathematical sense. E.g. Fermi-Dirac statistics etc. go under [quantum-statistics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-statistics) and perhaps [statistical-mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistical-mechanics), while the [spin-statistics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spin-statistics) tag is ideally reserved for issues related to the spin-statistics theorem).

II) More generally, the issue of tagging is non-trivial and difficult to make perfect. Since the system doesn't know which tags are close, and which tags are far apart in tag space (the metric is the [discrete metric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteMetric.html)), it is often better to have broad tags with simple rules rather than specific tags that nobody else will use consistently or have heard about. In plain English: it might be better to compromise and either (i) tag dromedary questions with the [camel](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camel) tag rather than introducing a new [dromedary](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dromedary) tag with the consequence that the system will no longer recognize that posts with [dromedary](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dromedary) and [camel](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camel) are likely very similar; or (ii) make [dromedary](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dromedary) a [synonym](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) of the [camel](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camel) tag, with the consequence that questions tagged with [dromedary](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dromedary) would automatically be retagged as [camel](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camel) by the system, even if experts of dromedaries would strongly object to this.

There will likely continue to be tags that cause various problems. E.g. the tags [mathematical-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-physics) and [specific-reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-reference) are often applied wrongly.

Non-descriptive tags, such as, e.g. [general-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-physics), [differential-equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-equations), [equations-of-motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equations-of-motion), etc, should be avoided as they serve little purpose. (Many questions on Phys.SE involve differential equations and equations of motion.)

An ambiguous tag, such as, e.g. [space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space) should either be replaced by [geometry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry), [spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacetime), [vacuum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vacuum), [space-travel](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-travel), etc, depending on context. Or the proper use of an ambiguous tag should be spelled out in the corresponding tag wiki. E.g. use of the [distributions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distributions) tag is explained in its [tag wiki](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distributions).

And so forth.

Comment: Ok, that's all nice and good, but there still needs to be a way to prevent misuse of the tag.

Comment: The logical way to do that is make [tag:covariance] a synonym of something.

Comment: The problem with this one, to borrow your animal metaphors, is that we have a bunch of questions tagged [tag:eight-legged-animal] that should either be tagged [tag:spider] or [tag:octopus]. There is no synonym of [tag:covariance] which will cover all of the questions it currently has.